# HtmlGenericControl - control is not rendered correctly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to setup a page dynamically is asp.net, 
my code is

```
HtmlGenericControl timeliner = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
timeliner.Attributes.Add("id", "timelineContainer");

HtmlGenericControl expandall = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
expandall.Attributes.Add("class", "timelineToggle");

HtmlGenericControl para = new HtmlGenericControl("p");

HtmlGenericControl asec = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
asec.Attributes.Add("class", "expandAll");
asec.InnerText = "+ expand all";

para.Controls.Add(asec);
expandall.Controls.Add(para);

timeliner.Controls.Add(expandall);

HtmlGenericControl bline = new HtmlGenericControl("br");
bline.Attributes.Add("class","clear");

HtmlGenericControl tlm1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
tlm1.Attributes.Add("class", "timelineMajor");

HtmlGenericControl tlmm1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h2");
tlmm1.Attributes.Add("class", "timelineMajorMarker");

HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerText = "1955";

HtmlGenericControl dl = new HtmlGenericControl("dl");
dl.Attributes.Add("class", "timelineMinor");


HtmlGenericControl dt = new HtmlGenericControl("dt");
dt.Attributes.Add("id", "32323");

HtmlGenericControl dla = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
dla.InnerText = "Test title";
dt.Controls.Add(dla);

dl.Controls.Add(dt);
tlmm1.Controls.Add(span);
tlm1.Controls.Add(tlmm1);
tlm1.Controls.Add(dl);
timeliner.Controls.Add(bline);            
timeliner.Controls.Add(tlm1);
```

now, for the first control "div" with id "timelineContainer", I have a css that gives it a left border, using this code my time line is displayed well, except the left-border, for some reason the height of this div is only 40px, as it supposed to be the parent of all the childrens.
Any idea?

Comment: Send us the generated html to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: **No idea!** You need to post CSS and mock-up of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm calling it for today. I'll send it on sunday-monday.

Answer (score 0):

The height will not be as a parent height. It will not be increased. It works only for width. You can set the height: inherited if you implicity set the height on the parent containers.

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 200px">
    <div id="child" style="width: inherited"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: will it work for height or not?? I don't have height of parent, it is dynamic